# MongoDB: Count Entries per Day

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I'm trying to migrate my SQL Queries to MongoDB. I'm stuck with getting the counts per day.
My MsSQL Query looks like this:

```
SELECT
datepart(DAY, Timestamp) as day,
datepart(MONTH, Timestamp) as month, 
datepart(YEAR, Timestamp) as year,
count(RowKey) as Counts               //uniq
FROM database
GROUP BY
datepart(YEAR, Timestamp),
datepart(MONTH, Timestamp), 
datepart(DAY, Timestamp) 
ORDER BY
datepart(YEAR, Timestamp),
datepart(MONTH, Timestamp), 
datepart(DAY, Timestamp) ASC
```

and the result:

[image: Old MsSQL Output]

The DB structure is flat :

```
{
  ...
  Timestamp : 2016-01-17T17:46:10.984Z,
  RowKey: 123,
  ...
}
{
  ...
  Timestamp : 2016-01-05T12:49:12.675Z,
  RowKey: 124,
  ...
}
...
```

I'm new to MongoDB and already tried [this](https://www.kevinhooke.com/2015/07/14/mongodb-aggregation-queries-for-counts-per-day-part-1/) but it didn't work the way i want it. I would be thankful for hints.

Comment: Could you please tell us how the data structure looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This could help you.

```
db.urcollection.aggregate(
  [

  {

 $project:

         {
           year: { $year: "$Timestamp" },
           month: { $month: "$Timestamp" },
           day: { $dayOfMonth: "$Timestamp" }
         }
     },
    {
    "$group":
     {
        "_id":{
        "year": "$year",
        "month": "$month",
        "day": "$day"
        } ,
        "YEAR": {
             "$first": "$year"
                 },
            "MONTH": {
             "$first": "$month"
            },
        "DAY": {
             "$first": "$day"
            }

     }
    },
   ]
)
```

Comment: Also You can use sort operation in aggregation pipeline

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but i don't get any records with this.
Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms

Comment: Do u use correct collection name? Is there any syntax error detected?